# multiply string element per int element from two arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning Java and looking for a comprehensive code of multiplying the elements from 2 arrays, possibly without importing anything to achieve it.

In Python it's quite easy:

```
a=['a','b','c','d']
b=[1,2,3,4]
[x*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd']
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Java, when the first array is an array of strings and the second is integers?

Comment: `without importing anything to achieve it` not even StringBuilder which seams perfect here?

Comment: @Pshemo yes, because i would like to understand how to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Java isn't going to support this kind of thing natively, and you'll need to perform some of your own logic to implement it. Let's say you've got your `String[]`..

```
String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
```

And you've got your `int[]`..

```
int[] b = {1,2,3,4};
```

Next, you'll need to check that the arrays are the same size.

```
if(a.length == b.length) {
    // Continue.
}
```

Then you need to implement a loop, to go through each item in the arrays.

```
for(int x = 0; x < a.length; x++)
{
    // Some looping code.
}
```

And you're going to grab each item.

```
String value = a[x];

int multiplier = b[x];
```

If you're not importing anything, you declare the total value:

```
String total = "";
```

But if you're allowing for a `StringBuilder`, then you'll import it and declare..

```
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
```

***NOTE:*** StringBuilder is strongly recommended here.

And then you're looping `multiplier` amount of times..

```
for(int y = 0; y < multiplier; y++)
{
    // If you use StringBuilder..
    total.append(value);

    // If you don't..
    total += value;
}

// If you use StringBuilder..
a[x] = total.toString();

// If you don't...
a[x] = total;
```

This will set the value of `a[x]` to the repeated `String`.

***NOTE***: Something that's also important is leaning good practise. If you're using Java code, it's considered terrible practise to repeatedly concatenate `String` objects. `StringBuilder` is more efficient, and is the Java standard. I would strongly recommend using this.

Have fun putting it all together!!

Comment: Thank you, i am trying to follow your guidelines. Am I going the right way with loops like these to grab the values?
`String [] strArr = new String[s];`

`//array for strings`

  `for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {`

   `strArr[i]=strings[i];`

   }

Answer (score 0):

To create string filled with multiple instances of same character like `"ccc"` you can firs create array of characters which will hold only 3 characters like

```
char[] myCharacters = new char[3];
```

Now this array is filled with zeroes (`'\0'`), so you need to fill it with desired character `'c'`. You simply do it using `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i<myCharacters; i++){
    myCharacters[i] = 'c';
}
```

After this your array will contain `['c', 'c', 'c']`.

Now you can use this array to create string using characters from it. To do so you just need to pass this array to String constructor like

```
String myString = new String(myCharacters);
```

And there you go. Now you have `"ccc"` String. Repeat these steps for each pair of elements from `a` and `b` arrays.

---

You can also use shorter version which kinds of do the same

```
String myString = new String(new char[3]).replace('\0','c');//will produce "ccc"
```